# Parser to match any tokens permutation?

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

Suppose I have a parser:

```
type Token = ...
type Tokens = Stream[Token]
class Parser[A](run: Tokens => Option[(Tokens, A)]) {...}
```

Suppose also I have simple parsers that match tokens `t1`, `t2`, `t3`:

```
def token[A](t: Token): Parser[A] = ... // create a parser to match "t"

val t1: Token = ...
val t2: Token = ...
val t3: Token = ...

val p1: Parser[A] = token(t1)
val p2: Parser[A] = token(t2)
val p3: Parser[A] = token(t3)
```

How to compose them and create a new parser to match *any* *permuation* of `t1, t2, t3` ?
Is there any standard parser combinator to do that ?

Comment: Maybe you can add a more concrete example of how you would use your `Token` / `Parser` ?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I don't believe any of the standard combinators will do this for you; you'd have to write your own. You might also consider accepting any sequence of t1/t2/t3 during parsing, then rejecting non-permutations during semantic analysis.

Comment: @Michael: Could you just elaborate on **why** you need the premutations?

Comment: @MartinSenne I thought about this question again and decided that I probably don't need it for now. Thank you all for the feedback.